# How to create tasklist using saved template through csom code

Tags: csom

I used the below code to create a `tasklist` for multiple `sharepoint` list items dynamically using a saved template.  I am getting the existing template but am unable to create a list using the template.  How can I create the `tasklist`?  Here is my code:

```
ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(GetSPUserName("SiteUserName"), GetSPpwd("SitePassword"));
                Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web,w=>w.ListTemplates);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                ListTemplate template = null;
                ListTemplateCollection ltc = ctx.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(web);
                ctx.Load(ltc);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();


            foreach (ListTemplate t in ltc)
            {
                if (t.InternalName == "Test.stp")
                {
                    template = t;
                    break;
                }
            }

            ListCreationInformation info = new ListCreationInformation();
            info.Title = "TestCreationOne";
            ctx.Load(template, tL => tL.Name, tL => tL.FeatureId, tL => tL.ListTemplateTypeKind);
            info.TemplateType = template.ListTemplateTypeKind;
            info.TemplateFeatureId = template.FeatureId;
            info.QuickLaunchOption = QuickLaunchOptions.DefaultValue;
            var list=web.Lists.Add(info);
            list.Update();
            ctx.Load(web.Lists);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to create the list, but does not apply the template to the list. I simplified the code and it worked. Here is a reference:

```
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(GetSPUserName("SiteUserName"), GetSPpwd("SitePassword"));

ListTemplate listTemplate = ctx.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(ctx.Web).GetByName("Test");

ctx.Load(listTemplate);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

ListCreationInformation info = new ListCreationInformation();
info.Title = "TestCreationOne";
info.ListTemplate = listTemplate;

var list = ctx.Web.Lists.Add(info);
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Question May be duplicate of: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/104611/